# How to get an Id of last inserted record in backend and display in flex

Tags: apache-flex, toad

How to get an Id of last inserted record from backend and display the same with success message as "RECORD INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY AS" +Id in flex...
am using Toad for sql server.......

Comment: What is your backend and what is your database?

Comment: am using TOAD for sql server.....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or 2008, use the function `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, otherwise use the variable `@@IDENTITY`. For example, if you have a table with an auto-increment column *id* and a column *value*:

```
DECLARE @newid int
INSERT INTO mytable (value) VALUES 'x'
SET @newid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
SELECT @newid
```